# How to specify emoji version of a Unicode character in HTML?

Tags: html, emoji

The Unicode entity:

> U+2714 HEAVY CHECK MARK

Has different encodings:

- **UCS4**: `0x00002714`
- **UTF-16**: `0x2714`
- **UTF-8**: `0xE2` `0x9C` `0x94`
- **HTML Entity**: `&#x2714;`

And that is all well and good. And if you have a Unicode file with that encoded character:

```
Offset    00 01 02 03
00000000: FF FE 14 27
```

it renders as the `HEAVY CHECK MARK` if you open it in a browser:

[image]

## But that's not the only U+2714

There is another U+2714. There are [two styles of U+2714:](https://www.iemoji.com/view/emoji/539/symbols/heavy-check-mark)

- **Text style**: ✔ (<kbd>U+2714</kbd>+<kbd>U+FE0E</kbd>)
- **Emoji style**: ✔️ (<kbd>U+2714</kbd>+<kbd>U+FE0F</kbd>)

And if put that second style, the Emoji style, into a text file:

```
Offset    00 01 02 03 04 05
00000000: FF FE 14 27 0F FE
```

it renders in a browser as `HEAVY CHECK MARK` but this time in *Emoji* style:

[image]

## How to encode that in HTML

Given the options are:

- **Text style**: <kbd>U+2714</kbd> <kbd>U+FE0E</kbd>
- **Emoji style**: <kbd>U+2714</kbd> <kbd>U+FE0F</kbd>

How do HTML encode that so that it shows up as `U+2714 HEAVY CHECK MARK` EMOJI STYLE?

Which is to say, these fail:

- `&heavycheckmarkemojistyle;`
- `&#x2714FE0F;`

what doesn't?

Comment: You are asking a Question, Great. I am following it too. As to learn something new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just specify the "emoji version" as a second entity.  Like this:

```
<p>
 &#x2714;<br/>
 &#x2714;&#xfe0f;<br/>
</p>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/upyc09gh/)